# Talend conditional expression trying to return a value from dimension table with if then else

Tags: java, talend

I'm new to Java due to a recent Talend adoption. I need help with the conditional statement below: it gives me an error that reads :

```
row3 cannot be resolved to a variable
```

All of the data types are strings.

```
row1.Vendor_Name.equals(row3.CP_VENDOR_NAME)?row3.VENDOR:row1.Vendor_Name
```

Syntactically my goal is : if `row1.Vendor_Name` has the same characters as `row3.CP_VENDOR_NAME` then `return row3.VENDOR` else `return row1.VENDOR_NAME`

Do I need to allow for NULL (read blank) fields? Any help and clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: show the class having the error.

Comment: Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve --- with these little code fragments you posted, it's impossible to tell you more than the compiler did.

Comment: I believe you are inside a tMap doing this. Giving the error message, it seems your input flow is no longer named "row3". Could you add a screenshot of your tMap settings please ?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your job layout. If you want more specific help you need to provide a schema or a screenshot of your job.

Specifically this means that row3 is not initialized. Without knowing your job, this could mean:

- row3 doesn't exist in this job
- row3 isn't connected to your component
- row3 will be used later, but isn't being used yet

Else than that your statement looks fine for your requirement.

Also, don't forget that you are not checking for `NULL`. When the statement is working, you might need to change it:

```
(row1.Vendor_Name != NULL && row1.Vendor_Name.equals(row3.CP_VENDOR_NAME)) ? 
 row3.VENDOR : row1.Vendor_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I turns out that I had the expression correct just in the wrong place. I had to move it from the inputtable.column to the outputtable.column of interest.

Also, after needing more filtering actions I found that I can add an expression to the input table at the bottom to act as a "global" filter by clicking on the white arrow at the top of the input table and therefore free up the outputtable.column expression location to use with another expression.

Hope this helps someone else. Thanks for all the quick replies.